# spinner value changes on scrolling list view

Tags: android

[image]

Spinner values changes on scrolling list view, for example if i am selecting NOT OK at first position from my spinner and then scroll down and come back to the top, the spinner values comes  automatically at zero position means at OK. here is my Adapter class and the data in list view is dynamic( varies ).

Code below:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<CustomerDetails> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        list = objects;
    }

    public View getView(final int modelPosition, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

            java.util.List<String> options = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();

            options.add("Ok");
            options.add("Not Ok");
            options.add("Not Recieved");

            holder.spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    options);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            holder.spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);                 

            if (myMap.containsKey(modelPosition)) {
                holder.spinner1.setSelection(myMap.get(modelPosition));
            }

            holder.spinner1.setTag(modelPosition);
            holder.spinner1
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {
                            myMap.put(modelPosition, position);

                            if (position == 1) {

                                Status_fos = parent.getItemAtPosition(
                                        position).toString();

                                db.updateMobileStatus(mobile_fos,
                                        Status_fos);

                            }
                            if (position == 2) {                         
                                Status_fos = parent.getItemAtPosition(
                                        position).toString();

                                db.updateMobileStatus(mobile_fos,
                                        Status_fos);
                            }
                            if (position == 3) {     
                                Status_fos = parent.getItemAtPosition(
                                        position).toString();

                                db.updateMobileStatus(mobile_fos,
                                        Status_fos);
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(list.get(modelPosition).getMobile());
        mobile_fos = list.get(modelPosition)
                .getMobile();

        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public Spinner spinner1;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView cid;

    }
}
```

Comment: Inserted image and removed some empty lines

Answer (score 0):

read this. it would be help you.
[Click Me](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Comment: Link is broken(not reachable)

Comment: You need to create an int variable which will keep track the adapter position.
wherever you are setting spinner update model class variable. And onBindViewHolder() get the variable value and set it.